# Setup and Query a database for Head-to-Head records

Tags: mysql

I am trying to learn mysql while creating something fun for my fantasy football league.  I am creating a table that will hold each game we have ever played and want to be able to query the table to show the head-to-head record for any given owners.  So for example Team A vs Team B or Team A vs Team D.

Here is what I was thinking for my table:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdGpU.jpg)

1st - If there is a better way to setup the table I am all ears.

2nd - I haven't been able to find away to pull this information, at least not that has made sense or worked for me.  Can anyone help get me started?

Thanks

Comment: The table setup looks nice and simple. It might make sense to set up a separate table for the team names in a relational database, but your way works. Are you wanting to see total scores over all time or by year?

Comment: What you have is fine for now. See UNION

Comment: To start with I would just like to be able to return the wins/losses between two teams all-time.  So for example I would like to show Team A's all-time record when they have played Team B.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straightforward way with your given tables.

```
SELECT COUNT( game_id ) 
FROM  `games` 
WHERE (
home_score > away_score
AND home_owner =  'TEAM A'
AND away_owner =  'TEAM B'
)
OR (
home_score < away_score
AND home_owner =  'TEAM B'
AND away_owner =  'TEAM A'
)
```

COUNT(game_id) is a function that will count the results of the query. In the WHERE statement, the first one returns where TEAM A (home) played TEAM B (away) and TEAM A won. The second returns where TEAM B (home) played TEAM A (away) and TEAM A won).

There's probably a more elegant way to construct the tables, but I think this is a good way to learn the basics of SQL.

Comment: This will get me started as I learn more.  Thank you I appreciate it!

Comment: When I run this query all I am getting is: COUNT(game_id)  
0.  Any ideas why it isn't returning a number?

Comment: I had an error between TEAM A and TEAM B in the first WHERE clause. I fixed it. See if it works now. Also, given your sample table, TEAM A never won against TEAM B. So unless the table has changed, 0 is the correct answer.